# Right way to produce elixir struct in macro

Tags: macros, elixir

I have the following design pattern: I have an elixir module, that responds to *growing/changing* amount of `functions/0`, called `Defaults`. I have also `CustomConfig` module, that is basically the struct, deriving defaults and assumed to be instantiated like:

```
%CustomConfig{ foo: "bar" }
```

where initialized properties are overwritten, others are taken from `Defaults` and those, not having a function with the same name in `Defaults` are rejected. So far, so good.

To implement this behaviour independent on content (the list of functions in `Defaults`,) I use a macro (in other module, since one can not use macro, defined in the same module, within struct declaration):

```
defmacro define_struct_with_defaults do
  quote do
    defstruct Map.to_list(
      quote do: unquote(Enum.reduce(Dict.keys(
                        Defaults.__info__(:functions)), %{}, fn(k, acc) ->
        Map.put(acc, :"#{k}", apply(Defaults, :"#{k}", []))
      end)))
  end
end
```

While this works fine, I am pretty sure, that there should be more straightforward/elegant/less-cumbersome way to achieve this functionality.

So my question would be: **how one could declare `defstruct` from the `Map` without dancing this paso doble around map-reduce**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a lot of indirection in your code that you really don't need. Examples:

1. `:"#{k}"` could be simply `k` as `k` is already an atom
2. You don't need `Dict.keys/1` because you can pattern match on the key inside the loop
3. You don't need a map because you can return a list directly from Enum.map (or from a comprehension)
4. You don't need a macro because you can pass any expression to `defstruct`

Here is how you can rewrite the code:

```
defmodule Default do
  def foo, do: 1
  def bar, do: 2
end

defmodule Config do
  data =
    # Get all functions with 0 arity and the respective default
    for {k, 0} <- Default.__info__(:functions) do
      {k, apply(Default, k, [])}
    end

  defstruct data
end
```

One of the benefits of Elixir is that you can [write assertive code](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2014/09/writing-assertive-code-with-elixir/). If you leverage that, you will become more and more confident in your code.

Comment: Thank you, the hint to use pattern match on the key is it. Honestly, I used macro just because I love the concept of macros being plain AST; I would remove it as well. Since I am moving from ruby I still have problems to code in Elixir in native way, but the more I do, the more I love it.

Comment: Glad you are enjoying! :)